# How do I add probability to a random number generator

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to add probability to my random number generator.

Here is the random number generator code.

```
'Generate 3 random numbers'
Dim rn As New Random
Dim result1, result2, result3 As Integer
result1 = rn.Next(1, 12)
result2 = rn.Next(1, 12)
result3 = rn.Next(1, 12)
```

So this code will generate 3 random numbers and save them into separate variables. 
I would like the following to happen.

```
1 has a 20% chance of being selected
2 has a 28% chance of being selected
```

values need to be between 1 and 12 and I need to select 3 numbers
Something along that line.

I found [this but it seems to be a little off topic?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx)

Could this be used for what I want?

Answer (score 4):

Make an array with 100 items. Put the value `1` into 20 spots in the array, the value `2` into 28 spots in the array, as so on. Then pick a random array index. Depending on your values and probabilities you could simplify or adjust the size of the array.

Alternatively, you can just store boundary pairs ( {1, 20}, {2, 48}, ... ), grab a random number less than your highest boundary value, and find the number for the smallest pair where your boundary value is greater than or equal to the random result. Here's an example:

```
Private rnd As New Random()
Public Function GetValue() As Integer 
    'max value is 100
    Dim boundaries = {
        {20, 48, 56, 60, 69, 74, 77, 82, 84, 88, 92, 100},
        { 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,  12}
    }

    Dim r As Integer = rnd.Next(1, 101) 'upper range is exclusive
    For i As Integer = 0 To boundaries.GetUpperBound(1)
        If boundaries(0, i) >= r Then Return boundaries(1, i)
    Next
    Throw New Exception() 'code should not be able to get here
End Function

Dim result1 As Integer = GetValue()
Dim result2 As Integer = GetValue()
Dim result3 As Integer = GetValue()
```

Comment: What a great idea, never looked at it like that. But i'm not entirely sure what would work as i'm wanting it to. Just to be sure the random values need to be between 1 and 12 and i need to select 3 numbers.

Comment: Sounds great, maybe that could work. Do you have an example piece of  code? I'm a little unsure how to do that?

Comment: Ill take a look and get back to you, sorry for that very slow reply.

Comment: Looks awesome!  But I want this code to run every time a button is clicked. This only works when the program loads. Thanks anyway!

Comment: So call the GetValue() method from your button as needed.

Comment: Just tested on button click, it only works once, It generates one set of numbers but wont work after I click it again.

Comment: Fixed it, moved the variables result1, result1, result1 inside of the button click function, works perfect! Thanks man. Great help.

Comment: Would you care to explain how I change the profitability for each number?  Thanks

Comment: Just change the first line of the boundaries array.

Comment: That makes scene, thanks mate, great help, awesome dude!

Comment: After some testing this does not work, this only will select the first number in the array, the next numbers are never generated.

Comment: Make sure you're getting a new random number.

Answer (score -2):

I while ago I was looking into generating a random Name list that mimicked he national USA population bases; the several thousand names needed mimicked the repetitive usage seen in the USA population.  To do this I needed a list of First names along with Sur names and their frequency of usage.  So I pulled the seed data from the Social Security Administration to obtain the top 1000 First and Sur names, along with their frequency of usage.

```
Think of three columns.  The first column is a list of names, the second their frequency seen in the population bases, and the third is the rolling totals of their frequency added row to row:

Marry, 57, 10
John, 40, 60
Lloyd, 2, 62
Zac, 1, 61

Read a seed file of any size into an area, along with the weight value for each name (or number).  This script assigns the rolling total weight values, then generates a random number between 1 and the sum of all weights.  Checks that random number against the rolling sum of weights to locate the number associated with that weight.

Looking at the above example you have a 57% chance to generate Marry, and a 1% chance to generate Zac.

The below script is a more robust example of the general idea.  It will generate random numbers between 1 – 25, based on the probability of their weights.  The portion of the script that generates the random numbers between 1 – 25 loops 128 times to give you 128 numbers based on their probability of being selected.

I basically used something like this to generate thousands of random names to mimic a population bases that mirrored the USA.


Dim iVar001, iVar002, iVar003
Dim iMin, iMax, iRand, iRandN
Dim iRow, iCol
Dim aName
Dim aList()

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' iMin is the lower range of random numbers, iMax is the upper
' range of random numbers being generated
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

iMin = 1
iMax = 25

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Create a dinamic sized 2D area used to generate a random number
' based on weighted Probability.  Array values array(0, 0) threw
' array(x, 0), where “x” is the upper range value of the number
' to be generated, contains the range of random numbers you will
' be generating.  Array values array(0, 1) to array(x, 1) contains
' the weight value for each number.  Array values array(0,2) to 
' array(x,2) contains the rolling sun of the weight values.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''


ReDim aList(iMax - 1, 2)
iVar001 = 0
Do While iVar001 <= (iMax - 1)
  Randomize
  aList(iVar001, 0) = iVar001 + 1
  aList(iVar001, 1) = Int(((20 * iMax) - iMin + 1)* Rnd + iMin)
  If iVar001 = 0 Then
    aList(iVar001, 2) = aList(iVar001, 1)
  Else
    aList(iVar001, 2) = aList(iVar001, 1) + aList(iVar001 - 1, 2)
  End If
  aName = aName & aList(iVar001, 0) & " - " & aList(iVar001, 1) & _
          " - " & aList(iVar001, 2) & vbCrLf
  iVar001 = iVar001 + 1
Loop

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Generate a message box containing the array values.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

MsgBox ("List of numbers," & vbCrLf& "weight values and" & _
        vbCrLf & "totals of weights." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & aName)


aName = ""
iCount000 = 1
iCount001 = 1
iCol001 = 0

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Generate a randon number between 1 and the total of weight 
' values.  Then step threw the array values until the the random 
' value is nolonger less than or equal to the running wieght value, 
' and record the number associated with that running weight value.
' The count of random =numbers generates is controled by the
' following Do While iCount000 <= 198.
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''' ''

Do While iCount000 <= 198
   Randomize
   iRand = Int((aList(UBound(aList,1),UBound(aList,2)) - iMin + 1)* Rnd + iMin)
   iVar001 = 0
   Do While iRand >= aList(iVar001, 2)
     iVar001 = iVar001 + 1
     iRandN = aList(iVar001, 0)
   Loop
   iCount000 = iCount000 + 1

   If iCount001 = "19" Then
      aName = vbCrLf & aName
      iCount001 = 0
   Else
      iCount001 = iCount001 + 1
   End If

   aName = iRandN & ", " & aName
Loop
MsgBox "List of random numbers in range " & iMin & " to " & iMax & "," & vbCrLf & _
       "based on weighted probability." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf  & aName
```